# "Servlet is currently unavailable" error on Tomcat

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

I'm trying to write a simple Java EE app in Eclipse EE Juno. Here is the file hierarchy of my project:

[image: project file hierarchy]

index.jsp:

```
<jsp:forward page="/departments.do"/>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>UniBudget</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Do</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>control.Controller</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Do</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The error I get:

```
HTTP Status 503 - Servlet Do is currently unavailable
```

And the question: why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Add a forward slash in your url pattern. `<url-pattern>/*.do</url-pattern>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kindly add a forward slash in your url pattern.

`<url-pattern>/*.do</url-pattern>`

Comment: Such a simple thing... But now after going to `http://localhost:8080/budget/` I get `The requested resource (/budget/) is not available.
`. Context root is set to `budget`. Not to mention `/*.do` addresses - the same thing.

Comment: When you hit the jsp page? Why don't you first make a simple html page. Place in WebContent and access it through: `http://localhost:8080/budget/myHtmlPage.html` to check whether application is deployed correctly and context root is ok.

Comment: You're right - apparently it is not working. I put some "hello world" in `index.jsp` and it wouldn't run. But I have totally no idea why - it looks like deployed properly...

Comment: Are you using any IDE to deploy the project or manually deploying it to Tomcat?

Comment: I just made a simple test - I created new Dynamic Web Project with `index.jsp` and some text inside. Nothing more. I worked at first. But then I tried to run the previous project (didn't work of course) and... the Test project stopped working as well! `The requested resource (/test/) is not available.
` How the hell is this possible??

Comment: I use Eclipse JEE (Juno), so everything is as automatic as it gets.

Comment: LoL. Start fresh! :) Delete both your projects. Publish it to Tomcat. Then make a new dynamic web project, and move step by step. Start by adding a simple html page first. Then move on to the jsp page and servlet .

Comment: I think I partly got it. WEB-INF/classes are not being generated at all and hence - no servlet can be found.

Comment: Oh! On toolbar in Eclipse click on Projects > Build Automatically. Might solve your problem :)

Comment: I thought the problem definitely needs more details. Please, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566170/servlet-not-working-in-newly-created-dynamic-web-project-in-eclipse-ee . And thanks for all the help so far! Upvote ;)

Comment: Just checked the question. It has already been answered! And your'e welcome! ;)