# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/wst/web/internal/deployables/IFlatDeployable

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

Servlet not working in newly created Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse Juno for Java EE. Here is how it goes, from scratch:

- I downloaded Eclipse EE (Juno), didn't change any of default config
- I downloaded latest Tomcat (7.0.30)
- In *Preferences > Server > Runtime Environments* I added new Apache Tomcat v7.0
- I created new Dynamic Web Project called UniBudget (context root: `budget`)
- I added new file (`index.jps` with *"it works!"* inside)

At this moment after adding project to server and running it I could see *"it works!"* on screen. So, deployment works.

- Next I added servlet file (`control.Controller.java`):

  ```
  package control;

  import java.io.IOException;
  import javax.servlet.ServletException;
  import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

  @WebServlet({ "/Controller", "*.do" })
  public class Controller extends HttpServlet {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      public Controller() {
          super();
      }

      protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
              HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          System.out.println("doGet()");
      }

      protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
              HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          System.out.println("doPost()");
      }

  }
  ```
- I changed `index.jsp` to look like this, nothing more:

  ```
  <jsp:forward page="/departments.do"/>
  ```
- And of course `web.xml`:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
      <display-name>UniBudget</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
          <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
          <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
          <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
              <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
              <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
          <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

      <!-- servlet definition -->
      <servlet>
          <servlet-name>Do</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>control.Controller</servlet-class>
      </servlet>
      <!-- servlet mapping -->
      <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>Do</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>Do</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/Controller</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
  ```
- Generated `.class` files have to be in `WEB-INF/classes` right? That's what I read. So: `Configure Build Path > Source tab > Browse >` I created `classes` folder in `WEB-INF` (in `Advanced` I linked to folder in file system: `... /UniBudget/build/classes`)
- This is the file hierarchy in project:

[image: file hierarchy in project]

- I cleaned and built the UniBudget project and republished to server. Cleaned the server.
- I thought I would work now (I mean displaying *"doGet()"* or *"doPost()"* in Console). But instead of printout in Console I got this error:

  ```
  HTTP Status 404 - /budget/departments.do

  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  type: Status report

  message: /budget/departments.do

  description: The requested resource is not available.
  ```
- the same happens when I try to directly access `http://localhost:8080/budget/Controller` (without redirection from `index.jsp`)

It looks like Eclipse could not see the servlet at all! Could you please point me where I make the mistake? I can't figure this out for hoours now.

---

**EDIT:**

After removing redundant annotation (`@WebServlet`), another error occurs:

```
HTTP Status 503 - Servlet Do is currently unavailable

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message Servlet Do is currently unavailable

description The requested service is not currently available.
```

Error in console:

```
wrz 24, 2012 9:34:15 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
WARNING: Servlet Do is currently unavailable
```

Not much. But that's all.

---

**EDIT:**

I found yet another error taking place here. I'm not even sure how to recreate it, but at least this one provides some more log info:

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 3

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type: Exception report

message: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 3

description: The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception: 

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 3

1: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
2:     pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
3: <jsp:forward page="/departments.do"/>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause: 

javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class control.Controller
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:746)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:716)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:65)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)


root cause: 

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: control.Controller
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:746)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:716)
    org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:65)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

---

**EDIT:**

Error during `project right click > Export > WAR file`:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/wst/web/internal/deployables/IFlatDeployable
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.JavaEEComponentExportOperation.getModuleParticipants(JavaEEComponentExportOperation.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.JavaEEComponentExportOperation.getParticipants(JavaEEComponentExportOperation.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.JavaEEComponentExportOperation.createFlatComponentArchiver(JavaEEComponentExportOperation.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.export(ComponentExportOperation.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.execute(ComponentExportOperation.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl$1.run(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.doExecute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.executeImpl(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.cacheThreadAndContinue(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.execute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.ui.DataModelWizard$1CatchThrowableRunnableWithProgress.run(DataModelWizard.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
```

Comment: set classpath in system environment variable

Comment: Could you elaborate? I'm not sure if I know how to do this.

Comment: *So: Configure Build Path > Source tab > Browse > I created classes folder in WEB-INF (in Advanced I linked to folder in file system: ... /UniBudget/build/classes)* You should **not** have performed this step! Eclipse will do it automagically while building a "Dynamic Web Project".

Comment: @BalusC I reverted the default output folder to `UniBudget/build`, but it changed nothing (and `WEB-INF/classes` is not being automatically (nor even automagically!) created by Eclipse).

Comment: It doesn't appear in project explorer, no. It however appears in the build. Look in the server's deploy folder.

Comment: @BalusC I cannot see the `.class` file in Windows Explorer in project's dir (it is only in `... \UniBudget\build\control`). Nor in Apache Tomcat dir.

Comment: The web.xml is redundant as well: you're using annotations. Why define the same thing twice?

Comment: @JBNizet because none of them (mapping in `web.xml` or annotations) do **not** work by themselves anyway.

Comment: @alex JB Nizet is correct. with the annotations defined in the servlet spec 3.0, you no longer need to add the servlet or servlet mappings in  the web.xml if you use the annotations. Use one or the other to avoid any confusion/errors. As a side note, this works for me no problem when I create the project. Are there any other settings you may have changed?

Comment: @Sean The project setup is very simple (as you can see) so there are not many settings I could change on the way. I tried to describe it as carefully as possible. BUT after I removed the servlet annotation, another type of error occurred. Please, take a look at updated question.

Comment: I'd imagine that he messed up the build settings somehow by touching the *Build Path* properties in an incorrect way. @alex: the deployed build is visible in the location as specific in the "Server path" under "Server location" in server's properties. If I were you, I'd just trash the project and recreate it and **not ever** touch the *Build Path* property until you really understand what it's doing under the covers.

Comment: @BalusC I created new project, with all the names changed, didn't touch a thing in build path - 404 error again. I already tried this on 2 separate computers and still the same problem! Damn!

Comment: With your new error, *"HTTP Status 503 - Servlet Do is currently unavailable"* we're however getting one step closer. This error indicates that the servlet registration is **recognized** (i.e. the `@WebServlet` or `<servlet>` did work!), but its construction or initialization as in `Controller controller = new Controller()` and `controller.init()` failed somehow. Although entirely superfluous, your constructor doesn't look weird. The cause of the construction/initialization problem should however be visible as an exception in the server log during server startup. Have you read the server logs?

Comment: @BalusC I'm even having difficulties recreating this error. I just appears like... random. I managed to get some more info out of this though - the question is updated. And thanks for all the help with this rather hard case!

Comment: Okay, the root cause is thus `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: control.Controller`. Well, this in turn indicates a build problem. Do you have automatic build turned on? (as by default). In Eclipse, *Project > Build Automatically* should be checked. If you manually export a WAR by rightclick project > *Export > WAR* and open it with some ZIP tool, do you then see the `Controller.class` file in `/WEB-INF/classes` folder? Another possible cause is that Tomcat its work folder is dirty. Try then the steps shown in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10941265

Comment: @BalusC automatic build is on. I do not export WAR manually. I performed the steps from the link - no change.

Comment: Exporting was just to confirm if the build is properly done as you can't seem to find the deploy folder. The Export-as-WAR option is using exactly the same build process.

Comment: @BalusC oh, sorry, I didn't read that carefully and thought you meant something else. But - there is an error during WAR export! Take a look at updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/wst/web/internal/deployables/IFlatDeployable
> ```

Whoops. That's a pretty serious error, this class is namely internal to Eclipse. This has been reported once as [Eclipse issue 388698](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388698), but this was unfortunately closed off as `WORKSFORME`. This seems to be an environment/platform/configuration specific problem after all. I'd consider re-posting the same issue along with as much as possible detail about the environment used (OS make/version, JRE/JDK make/version, hardware specs, etc).

I have personally not tried Juno yet (I usually wait for a SR1 to be released around winter so that all major teething issues are covered), but if completely deleting the Eclipse installation and re-unzipping it doesn't work, then I'd suggest to try to step back to the previous Eclipse version, which is [Indigo SR2](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/indigo/sr2). Make sure that you download the right version for your platform (32bit vs 64bit).

Answer (score 0):

For me the

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/wst/web/internal/deployables/IFlatDeployable
```

error was caused by the following plugin:

```
WTP Patches for org.eclipse.jst.web_core.feature 3.4.0.v201207092049-20F8O7w312318212711
```

After the plugin was disabled I was able to package a war using Eclipse and deploy it.

(This solution comes from the URL [Bug 388698 - Error exporting WAR file](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388698) mentionned by BalusC)